# Asp.Net Core middleware pathstring startswithsegments issue

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Have a Asp.NET Core 2.0 application and I would like to map any path that does not start with `/api` to just reexecute to the root path.  I added the below but doesn't seem to work:

```
app.MapWhen(
   c => !c.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
   a => a.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/")
);
```

Not using MapWhen() and just using `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/")` works for all paths not root.  Just want to add filtering for all paths not root and not `/api`.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Branched pipeline does not work correctly here because you have not added MVC middleware after status code page middleware. Here is the correct pipeline setup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.MapWhen(
        c => !c.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
        a =>
        {
            a.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/");
            a.UseMvc();
        });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Note that middleware order matters here, you should add status code page middleware before MVC.

However using conditional pipeline seems like overkill here. You could achieve your goal with [URL Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x):

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"^(?!/api)", "/", skipRemainingRules: true);
app.UseRewriter(options);

app.UseMvc();
```