# ASP.NET Core and Angular redirecting API 404 calls

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, routes

I'm running ASP.NET Core and Angular CLI.

The API Calls run through routing '/api/etc' everything else is static or Angular Routing.

I've got everything running nicely until I ran into a 404 (notfound) in one of my API calls. And this triggered a redirect to "/".

#### startup.cs

The `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` reroutes all calls to "/" which it the source of my troubles.

A. I need the 404 calls (sans '/api/**') to end up in '/' so Angular can handle it.

B. I need the '/api/**' calls not to be ignored whatever the response is.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // This is needed to get Angular handling the routing
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/");

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I've tried [app.MapWhen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692922/asp-net-core-middleware-pathstring-startswithsegments-issue) but it didn't do what it promised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've taken the original [UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/3a868d87a2458fd025ca71e2538b3a72f67c7c50/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesExtensions.cs#L164) and added an extra if to check if the error occurred in a API call.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute(app, "/", null);
    app.UseMvc();

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc();
}


public static IApplicationBuilder UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        string pathFormat,
        string queryFormat = null)
{
    if (app == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
    }

    return app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
    {
        var newPath = new PathString(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, pathFormat, context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode));
        var formatedQueryString = queryFormat == null ? null : string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, queryFormat, context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);
        var newQueryString = queryFormat == null ? QueryString.Empty : new QueryString(formatedQueryString);

        // Ignore API calls << this if is added 
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            await context.Next(context.HttpContext);
            return;
        }

        var originalPath = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
        var originalQueryString = context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
        // Store the original paths so the app can check it.
        context.HttpContext.Features.Set<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>(new StatusCodeReExecuteFeature()
        {
            OriginalPathBase = context.HttpContext.Request.PathBase.Value,
            OriginalPath = originalPath.Value,
            OriginalQueryString = originalQueryString.HasValue ? originalQueryString.Value : null,
        });

        context.HttpContext.Request.Path = newPath;
        context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString = newQueryString;
        try
        {
            await context.Next(context.HttpContext);
        }
        finally
        {
            context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString = originalQueryString;
            context.HttpContext.Request.Path = originalPath;
            context.HttpContext.Features.Set<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>(null);
        }
    });
}
```